# List Azure role assignments using Azure Logicapps

Tags: azure-logic-apps, rbac

I'm new using logic apps and I'm trying to get information about RBAC assignments to users. I was using graph to get information about AD user as you can see in this image below.
[image]
In this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-list-rest) I found how to list this information but using management.azure.com and I don't know what kind of permissions my logicapp needs and if this step is configured correctly.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to **enable system managed identity in logic app** and also need to **add role assignment for logic app in subscription**.

I have reproduced issue from my side and below are steps I followed,

1. Created logic app as shown below,
   [image]
2. Enabled system managed identity in logic app,
   [image]
3. When I run logic app got below error,

   *"code": "AuthorizationFailed",
   "message": "The client 'XXXXX' with object id 'XXXXX' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/read' over scope '/subscriptions/XXXXX' or the scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please refresh your credentials."*

[image]

4. Added role assignment for the created logic app as a contributor role in Subscription access control,

[image]
5. After adding role assignment, logic app ran successfully,

[image]
Reference [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-list-portal)